# Wcf service - request and response data

Tags: wcf, wsdl

What is the easiest way to see the input data elements and output data elements of a wcf service? (going through wsdl will be time consuming due to multiple type references) For ex. I can use soapUI to see the input data elements, but I have to know what input data should be provided to execute it and see the the output data elements. Is there any tool that can take the wsdl and provide a clean view of input and output schemas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a tool such as [`svcutil.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733(v=vs.110).aspx) or the "Add Service Reference" dialog in Visual Studio for that. You'd point the tool to the WSDL, and it woill generate *classes* with the contract defined by the WSDL. The code, even though it's auto-generated, is fairly readable.

Comment: Thanks. Isn't there a way we can generate service input and service output (may be sample input/output xml, or simple tree-like view) based on wsdl? The intent is not to write a service client here, it is only for "seeing" the input and output of service for analysis (without executing the service). This will serve as a quick-reference for the  service

Comment: Not that I know of. But you can use the [`WsdlImporter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.wsdlimporter.aspx) class to write a program that imports the WSDL and present their operations as you want.